# Add single table data phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a wordpress site I restored and imported my DB using phpmyadmin. The data for some tables are not importing though.

How can I get the data from my sql file (viewing using notepad) --

```
INSERT INTO `tr_rg_lead` (`id`, `form_id`, `post_id`, `date_created`,
`is_starred`, `is_read`, `ip`, `source_url`, `user_agent`, `currency`,
`payment_status`, `payment_date`, `payment_amount`, `payment_method`,
`transaction_id`, `is_fulfilled`, `created_by`, `transaction_type`,
`status`) VALUES (1, 1, 0, '2016-01-02 03:07:59', 0, 0, .....
```

Into the specific table that's already created?

Comment: what is the actual error ?

Comment: Specify your error or post screenshot of error you are getting.